# Не получается перенаправить все пакеты посредством iptables к конкретному url на localhost

Tags: linux, iptables

У меня на компьютере стоит сервер, который прослушивает http://localhost:3000. Я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы все запросы, которые идут на адрес http://api.lingualeo.com/addword (внешний сервис), перенаправлялись iptables на http://localhost:3000

Что я делаю:

`# sysctl -w net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet=1
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000`

Но это не работает, а вывод `iptables -nvL` не показывает, что DNAT работает.

Также я попробовал 
`# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -o lo -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000` 
и это также не подействовало и `iptables -nvL` остался чист

Удивительно, но **заблокировать** все запросы на http://api.lingualeo.com/addword командой `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j DROP` у меня получилось.

---

OS: archlinux x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи правила DNAT вы изменили адрес назначения в пакете - но адрес отправителя остался прежним. Когда сервер отвечает обратно, он отправит пакет напрямую отправителю - но отправитель-то не в курсе, что адрес назначения поменялся! В итоге, ответный пакет окажется отброшен. Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам надо добавить правило SNAT для того, чтобы скрыть исходный адрес отправителя.

Но есть еще и другая проблема. В одном HTTP-соединении может быть сделано два запроса на разные адреса. Поэтому будет куда лучше, если запросы к этому не будут фильтроваться на уровне iptables, а будут перенаправляться все - ваш же сервер выступит в качестве прокси-сервера если запрос будет предназначен не ему.

Comment: 1. Но мне в принципе и не нужно, чтобы мой сервер отвечал отправителю (так даже лучше: расширение не отображает ошибки) 2. Перенаправлять все HTTP-пакеты на сервер? `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000`? Дело в том, что даже эта не работает, `iptables -nvL` не показывает, что эта команда выполнилась

Comment: Я наверное понял, вы про начало сеанса TCP? "Рукопожатие"?

Comment: Это применимо к любой части сеанса TCP. И без этого запрос может попросту не суметь отправиться целиком.

Comment: И какой SNAT поставить?

Comment: *И какой SNAT поставить?* — внешний ip-адрес (если он один, конечно).

Comment: Команда `ip addr show wlp3s0` показывает `inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp3s0`

тогда команда будет `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.2/24`? так? просто я не совсем понял

Comment: @BjornMelgaard, да, только не `--to`, а `--to-source` (см. `man iptables` и/или `man iptables-extensions`). / вы не упомянули меня, и я не получил оповещения, а заглянул сейчас в этот вопрос чисто случайно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет, все равно не работает, пришлось применить `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2`, так как `Bad IP address "192.168.1.2/24"` и SNAT можно использовать только с INPUT/POSTROUTING. Интересно то, что обе команды так и не показываются в `iptables -nvL` / прошу прощения и спасибо за проявленный интерес